# Как создать раздел system с помощью parted в android?

Tags: android, восстановление, partition

У меня в телефоне пропали разделы *system*, *product* и *vendor*. У меня установлен *TWRP*. При установке ОС выводит такую ошибку:

```
unable to mount /system_root (block device required)
unable to mount /product (block device required)
unable to mount /vendor (block device required)
```

При прошивке с **Фастбута** говорит что такие разделы не существуют. Как теперь установить ОС? Сначала нужно создать эти разделы, а потом саму Андроид или как? Телефон Redmi 9A.
***parted*** выводит такой результат:

```
dandelion:/ # parted /dev/block/mmcblk0                                                                           
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/block/mmcblk0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: MMC DA4032 (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 31.3GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name           Flags
 1      32.8kB  1081kB  1049kB               boot_para      msftdata
 2      1081kB  68.2MB  67.1MB               recovery       msftdata
 3      68.2MB  68.7MB  524kB                para           msftdata
 4      68.7MB  89.7MB  21.0MB               expdb          msftdata
 5      89.7MB  106MB   16.8MB               gsort          msftdata
 6      106MB   115MB   8389kB               ffu            msftdata
 7      115MB   987MB   872MB   ext4         cust           msftdata
 8      987MB   996MB   8389kB               vbmeta_system  msftdata
 9      996MB   1004MB  8389kB               vbmeta_vendor  msftdata
10      1004MB  1005MB  1049kB               frp            msftdata
11      1005MB  1039MB  33.6MB  ext4         nvcfg          msftdata
12      1039MB  1106MB  67.1MB  ext4         nvdata         msftdata
13      1106MB  1129MB  23.7MB  ext4         md_udc         msftdata
14      1129MB  1163MB  33.6MB               metadata       msftdata
15      1163MB  1171MB  8389kB  ext4         protect1       msftdata
16      1171MB  1183MB  11.4MB  ext4         protect2       msftdata
17      1183MB  1191MB  8389kB               seccfg         msftdata
18      1191MB  1242MB  50.3MB  ext4         persist        msftdata
19      1242MB  1244MB  2097kB               sec1           msftdata
20      1244MB  1247MB  3146kB               proinfo        msftdata
21      1247MB  1247MB  524kB                efuse          msftdata
22      1247MB  1352MB  105MB                md1img         msftdata
23      1352MB  1353MB  1049kB               spmfw          msftdata
24      1353MB  1354MB  1049kB               scp1           legacy_boot, msftdata
25      1354MB  1355MB  1049kB               scp2           msftdata
26      1355MB  1356MB  1049kB               sspm_1         legacy_boot, msftdata
27      1356MB  1357MB  1049kB               sspm_2         msftdata
28      1357MB  1374MB  16.8MB               gz1            msftdata
29      1374MB  1391MB  16.8MB               gz2            msftdata
30      1391MB  1458MB  67.1MB               nvram          msftdata
31      1458MB  1460MB  2097kB               lk             legacy_boot, msftdata
32      1460MB  1462MB  2097kB               lk2            msftdata
33      1462MB  1529MB  67.1MB               boot           msftdata
34      1529MB  1538MB  8389kB               logo           msftdata
35      1538MB  1546MB  8389kB               dtbo           msftdata
36      1546MB  1551MB  5243kB               tee1           legacy_boot, msftdata
37      1551MB  1560MB  8913kB               tee2           msftdata
38      1560MB  6392MB  4832MB               super          msftdata
39      6392MB  6401MB  8389kB               vbmeta         msftdata
40      6401MB  6853MB  453MB                cache          msftdata
41      6853MB  31.2GB  24.4GB               userdata       msftdata
42      31.2GB  31.3GB  45.1MB               otp            msftdata
43      31.3GB  31.3GB  16.8MB               flashinfo      msftdata
```